# Errors in dumping a remote Git based SVN repository over HTTP

Tags: git, bash, svn, github, repository

I'm running into several errors trying to clone/mirror a GitHub repo. I've tried doing this over HTTPS locally, or server to server (so I can hotcopy it back into our SVN server repo). The BASH script I'm using that should dump the repo fails with these errors:

> $ svnsync init file:///home/jdaniel/www/clone/rest https://github.com/ehime/Restful-MVC-Prototype
>   svnsync: E125005: Wrong or unexpected property value
>   svnsync: E125003: Bogus date
>
> $ svnsync sync file:///home/jdaniel/www/clone/rest https://github.com/ehime/Restful-MVC-Prototype
>   svnsync: E200007: The requested report is unknown.

I've also tried using `snvrdump` but get a similarly weird problem:

```
$ svnrdump dump https://github.com/ehime/CLI-Parser

SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 3

UUID: cfadd8e1-f89a-a5da-a424-ce57b7db7bff

Revision-number: 0
Prop-content-length: 163
Content-length: 163

K 10
git-commit
V 0

K 10
svn:author
V 0

K 8
svn:date
V 0

K 7
svn:log
V 0

K 25
svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url
V 39
/ehime/Restful-MVC-Prototype/!svn/bln/0
PROPS-END

* Dumped revision 0.
Revision-number: 1
Prop-content-length: 299
Content-length: 299

K 10
git-commit
V 40
ec089b697a5698f71d5edffb2f90b1385acbc53f
K 10
svn:author
V 5
ehime
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2013-08-16T17:16:26.000000Z
K 7
svn:log
V 61
Initial repository configuration with working hello world bs

K 25
svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url
V 39
/ehime/Restful-MVC-Prototype/!svn/bln/1
PROPS-END

svnrdump: E200007: The requested report is unknown.
```

This ends with the same `Requested report is unknown` error.

All GitHub repos that I've tested so far (4-5) throw that report unknown error. Please help.

Comment: My bet is that your tools fail because github only emulates the subset of the subversion protocol (basically webdav) that is required to do checkouts and commits, while the tools you're using require a real subversion server on the other end. Have you tried checking out the repository using git and then [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) to push the entire history to subversion?

Comment: Clearly, the best way to access a GitHub repo is to use Git ;-). Once you have the local copy, you can use whatever tool works for you to commit back to the SVN repo and you're not limited by GitHub's emulation of SVN.

Comment: @Phillip Can you provide a step-by-step Git[Hub] to svn repo as an answer? Looks like this is the only way this can be achieved - and would therefore be the "correct" answer that is missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@SimonSobisch

Per Simons request, here is the scripts that I ended up writing to move Subversion into GH

```
#!/usr/local/env bash
# Converter for GitHub -> Subversion Repositories

# CPR : Jd Daniel :: Ehime-ken
# MOD : 2013-03-09 @ 16:26:53; 2017-01-31 @ 13:36:15 Simon Sobisch
# VER : Version 1c

# the Github SVN url to clone from
URL={THE_SVN_URL} # https://github.com/user/repo/

# the SVN url to clone to
REPO={THE_REPO_ROOT} in # svn+ssh://user@domain.com/api/svn_name

# the SVN structure
SVNTRUNK=${SVN_TRUNK-trunk}
SVNTAGS=${SVN_TAGS-tags}
SVNBRANCHES=${SVN_BRANCHES-branches}

# use the trunk, branch, etc... I'm using the trunk
SVN="${REPO}/$SVNTRUNK"


clear || cls;                  # set -x #debug

## if you want to burn and rebuild your repo, uncomment below
#
#echo "Burning Repo..."
#svn rm    $REPO/{$SVNTRUNK,$SVNTAGS,$SVNBRANCHES} -m "Burning..."

#echo "Rebuilding Repo...."
#svn mkdir $REPO/{$SVNTRUNK,$SVNTAGS,$SVNBRANCHES} -m "Rebuilding..."

# cleanup
find -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '.*' |xargs rm -rf; # tmp

# dirs
SVN_FOLDER=`pwd`"/svn"
GIT_FOLDER=`pwd`"/git"


# revs
ENDREV=`svn info $URL |grep Revision: |awk '{print $2}'`
CURREV=1

  mkdir -p $SVN_FOLDER $GIT_FOLDER

echo -e "\nLinking SVN repo\n"

  cd $SVN_FOLDER
  svn co $SVN .

echo -e "\nDownloading GIT repo\n"

  cd $GIT_FOLDER
  git svn init -s $URL \
  -T $SVNTRUNK \
  -t $SVNTAGS \
  -b $SVNBRANCHES \
  --prefix=svn/

  # Set authors so we get prettier authors
  if [ -f "../authors" ]; then
     git config svn.authorsfile ../authors
  fi

  echo -e "\nFound ${ENDREV} revisions\n"

  for (( REVISION=$CURREV; REVISION<$ENDREV+1; REVISION++ ))
  do

    cd $GIT_FOLDER

    echo -e "\n---> FETCHING: ${REVISION}\n"

    git svn fetch -r$REVISION;                echo -e "\n"
    git rebase `git svn find-rev r$REVISION`; echo -e "\n"

    # STATUS: git log -p -1 `git svn find-rev r19` --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort -u
    ADD=$(git log -p -1 `git svn find-rev r$REVISION` --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A |awk '{printf "%s ", $1}')
    MOD=$(git log -p -1 `git svn find-rev r$REVISION` --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=M |awk '{printf "%s ", $1}')
    DEL=$(git log -p -1 `git svn find-rev r$REVISION` --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=D |awk '{printf "%s ", $1}')

      # copy new files
      for i in $ADD
      do
         cp --parents $i $SVN_FOLDER/
      done


      # copy modified files
      for i in $MOD
      do
         cp --parents $i $SVN_FOLDER/
      done


    # set opts for SVN logging
    HASH=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:'Hash: %h <%H>')
    AUTHOR='Jd Daniel <dodomeki@gmail.com>'  # or $(git log -1 --pretty="%cn <%cE>")

    TMPDATE=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ad --date=iso8601)
    DATE=$(date --date "$TMPDATE" -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N" |sed 's/.....$/Z/g')

    LOGMSG=$(git log -1 --pretty=%s)

    # move to svn
    cd $SVN_FOLDER


    # burn file if it exists....
    if [ "$DEL" != "" ]; then
      for i in $DEL
      do
         test -f $i && svn --force rm $i
      done
    fi

    # first round of additions....
    [ -z "$ADD" ] || svn --force add $ADD
    [ -z "$MOD" ] || svn --force add $MOD


    # try 2 for adding in case we missed ? files
    ADDTRY=$(svn st . |grep "^?" |awk '{print $2}')
    [ -z "$ADDTRY" ] || svn --force add $ADDTRY

    # do commit
    svn ci -m "$LOGMSG"$'\n\n'"$HASH"

    # servers pre-revprop-change
    #  cp hooks/pre-revprop-change.tmpl pre-revprop-change; chmod +x pre-revprop-change
    #  if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:author" ]; then exit 0; fi
    #  if [ "$ACTION" = "M" -a "$PROPNAME" = "svn:date" ]; then exit 0; fi
    #  echo "Changing revision properties other than svn:log, svn:author and svn:date is prohibited" >&2

    # change this commits author and date
    svn propset --revprop -r HEAD svn:author "$AUTHOR"
    svn propset --revprop -r HEAD svn:date   "$DATE"

  done

exit
```

Anyway, git-svn supports this really well, with just a slight variation on the usual git svn clone.

Instead of the standard project/trunk|branches|tags we use a slightly different `parent/trunk|branches|tags/project`
so you’ll see I specify the -`T/-t/-b` flags.

```
git svn init
```

Here is what I do, from the existing local git repo:

```
# Create the project directory in subversion
$ /usr/bin/svn mkdir
  https://example.com/svn/parent/trunk/project
  -m "Make project directory."
Committed revision 200.

# Initialize git-svn, doesn't fetch anything yet
$ git svn init https://example.com/svn/
  -T parent/trunk/project
  -t parent/tags/project
  -b parent/branches/project
  --prefix=svn/

# Set authors so we get prettier authors
$ git config svn.authorsfile ../authors

# Now pull down the svn commits
$ git svn fetch
W: Ignoring error from SVN, ...
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn ...
This may take a while on large repositories
r200 = (guid) (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)

# We should now see our svn trunk setup under our svn remote
$ git branch -av
* master            c3a7161 The latest git commit.
  remotes/svn/trunk 3b7fed6 Make project directory.

# Now we want to take all of our local commits and 
# rebase them on top of the new svn/trunk
$ git rebase svn/trunk
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: First git commit
Applying: The latest git commit

# Now we should see our local commits applied
# on top of svn/trunk
$ git lg
* 52b7977 (HEAD, master) The latest git commit
* a34e162 First git commit
* 3b7fed6 (svn/trunk) Make project directory.

# Everything is cool, push it back to svn
$ git svn dcommit
Committing to https://example.com/svn/parent/trunk/project
...

–prefix=svn
```

One flag I especially like lately, which you can also use with `git svn clone`, is `--prefix=svn/`.

This will prefix all of your tracking branches of the remote Subversion branches, tags, and trunk with svn/, making it look a whole lot like the usual origin/ idiom used by regular git remotes.

With the tracking branches having a prefix, you can also use them as local branch names, e.g.:

```
# Name your copy of svn/trunk "trunk" instead of "master"
$ git checkout -b trunk master
Switched to a new branch 'trunk'

$ git branch -d master
Deleted branch master (was 33c3136).

$ git branch -av
* trunk             33c3136 Latest svn commit
* remotes/svn/trunk 33c3136 Latest svn commit
```

Then if you have other branches you want to track:

```
$ git checkout -b featurea svn/featurea
```

Comment: @SimonSobisch here's that answer you wanted

Comment: And if this doesn't work I have about three other ways, just ping me ;)

Comment: The first script currently runs so I cannot tell about the final result - just some possible issues I want to mention for it:
1. take a lot of time if you use this, even if the svn repository is local (I've created a fresh one locally, accessing it via `file:` protocol)
2. check for git and svn binary (my fresh test PC didn't have git installed) and for svn revprop hook - the script currently doesn't test for this. 3. Likely doesn't work as it should - at least I get a lot of "cp: cannot stat `some-file`: No such file or directory" warnings when running (the first) script

Comment: I've aborted the test of the first script - FETCHING 245 after 90 minutes... Something additional that I've recognized: "property 'svn:date' set on repository revision 23" is shown four times and the same message for revision 27 is still shown when fetching 245.
I'll try the other script tomorrow.

Comment: Tested the second approach with a fresh svn repository (with the trunk/branch/tags as rev1) and a fresh git clone. Aborted with a merge conflict when "Applying: " the 63th change.

Comment: Result: r1 = 8f491d4f680cee1012fda7291498313ad77b2dba (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Initial Commit
Applying: ...62 entries
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       some/Afile.java
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging some/Afile.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in some/Afile.java
Patch failed at 0063 Async Support
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

Is the repo https://github.com/GitMensch/xdev.server corrupt? Any idea how to move on?

Comment: I've thought I knew why the first script didn't worked: it always checked against `r19`, I've changed it to `r$REVISION` but it still shows the same errors: `cp: cannot stat... No such file or directory` and `svn: warning: W266020: ... not found`

Comment: I've awarded this answer even if it doesn't solve the concrete issue - but it is the best answer I found so far.
@ehime Could you check the problems against https://github.com/RapidClipse/xdev.server please?